# Express.js API fails to receive cookies from front end

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

In a React.js app I am using the `js-cookie` library to set 2 cookies. I am able to log the cookies to the console. I also see both cookies in a chrome extension, and the keys/values match.

I am sending the cookies via a fetch request that has a key for `credentials: 'include'`

```
async function requestAllAccountData() {
  const allAccountDataEndpoint = buildUrl(REACT_APP_HTTPS_BACKEND_DOMAIN, {
    path: '/account-data/all'
  });

  console.log('allAccountDataEndpoint', allAccountDataEndpoint);

  try {
    const response = await fetch(allAccountDataEndpoint, {
      method: 'get',
      mode: 'cors',
      credentials: 'include', // for cookie passage to back end
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
      },
    });

    const allAccountData = await response.json();
    console.log('allAccountData',allAccountData);
    return allAccountData;
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(error);
  }
}
```

An express endpoint with the following code fails to print the cookie values. Later in the code the lack of cookie keys/values sends control down a sad path.

```
router.get('/all', async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  console.log('req.cookies', req.cookies); 
  // [Object: null prototype] {}

  console.log('number of cookies keys', Object.keys(req.cookies).length);
  // 0
```

In server.ts I am bringing in the `cookie-parser` package as an invoked middleware:

```
const corsConfigured = cors({
  credentials: true, // this setting should accept cookies
  origin: true,
});

server
  .use(corsConfigured)
  .use(cookieParser())
  .use(Express.json())
  .use('/account-data', accountDataRouter);
  // ^ this is the router shown in the prior code sample
```

What am I failing to do to cause the cookies not to be visible inside the route handler?

The cookies have no special options set on them.

**Update: Request Information**

In Google Chrome I do not see a header for the cookies in either the GET or OPTIONS request:

```
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 401 
Remote Address: [2600:1f16:d83:1201::6e:1]:443
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-origin: http://localhost:3000
content-length: 33
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
date: Thu, 01 Oct 2020 16:05:30 GMT
etag: W/"21-EAAxQ8w9ulq766ONDoxsOSjUMSY"
status: 401
vary: Origin
x-powered-by: Express
:authority: asanarepeater.ngrok.io
:method: GET
:path: /account-data/all
:scheme: https
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,th;q=0.8
content-type: application/json
origin: http://localhost:3000
referer: http://localhost:3000/
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: cross-site
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36
```

.

```
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 204 
Remote Address: [2600:1f16:d83:1201::6e:1]:443
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-headers: content-type
access-control-allow-methods: GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE
access-control-allow-origin: http://localhost:3000
content-length: 0
date: Thu, 01 Oct 2020 16:05:28 GMT
status: 204
vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers
x-powered-by: Express
:authority: asanarepeater.ngrok.io
:method: OPTIONS
:path: /account-data/all
:scheme: https
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,th;q=0.8
access-control-request-headers: content-type
access-control-request-method: GET
origin: http://localhost:3000
referer: http://localhost:3000/
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: cross-site
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: Can you try using browser developer console and see if Cookie header is present in the request? This helps to narrow down whether it's the fetch not sending cookie or nodejs not parsing properly

Comment: @EricWong Thanks for mentioned that. I do not see a cookie header in the GET or OPTIONS request, now posted in the original post

Comment: Seems your react.js app domain is different from api domain? apparently its the react app is at localhost but the API is at asanarepeater.ngrok.io ?

Comment: @EricWong That is correct, ngrok is needed to use HTTPS, because the outside service requires the use of HTTPS.

Comment: Well then so your site is on localhost, you set the cookie with js-cookie, then the cookie should be in localhost domain? And you are fetching ngrok expecting the cookie?

Comment: @EricWong. That explains it, thanks. Backend is still pretty new to me. I'll look into alternatives to pass that information

Comment: Glad that you figured out the problem. Hope it did not sound too rude throwing off so much questions.

Comment: For JWT, one common approach to use the Authorization Bearer header and scheme, you might want to check that out